# Displaying math in Pluto.jl

Tags: julia, pluto.jl

Pluto.jl is very nice. However, I have a small problem that I could not solve by myself. Please have a look at the problem through this nWME (not Working, but Minimal Example to explain the situation)

```
Cell 1: varname = "a";
Cell 2: md"If I use: The variable is $varname, then I could not have the same math character as when I use: The variable is $a$."
```

How can I display a string (e.g, varname) in math mode in the Markdown in Pulto.jl?
Here is what I tried:

```
Cell 3: md"The variable name is ``$varname``"
```

but the result is not as expected.